# Screensaver in Lion

Tags: macos, mac, screensaver

I like to use events and albums from iPhoto as my screensavers. Lately, only some events and albums show up when I go into preferences>screensavers.  If I go out and come back in, most will then show,  but once I choose an event or album it doesn't reliably show up when the screensaver should start.  I get message that folder is empty of pictures and to choose a different one.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would verify that your iPhoto library is fully intact.  To do this:

1. Open Finder and open the `/Applications` folder.
2. Scroll down to iPhoto.
3. Pressing `Option` and `Command`, double-click iPhoto.

You'll be presented with a **Rebuild Photo Library** window.  I would check the following options:

- Repair the iPhoto Library Database
- Rebuild the photos' small database
- Examine and repair iPhoto Library file permissions

Click `Rebuild` and wait until the process is complete.  Once it's all done, go back to System Preferences and check to see if you can select iPhoto and albums okay.

If the issue persists, I'd take a look at [this article on Mac OS X Hints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120112094116261) and follow the steps listed there.

Good Luck!